# Does anyone know of an advanced diff tool for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, diff

I'm looking for a diff tool that can analyse my code and tell me what has changed on a construct by construct basis.

For instance, if I cut and paste a method from the start of my file and put it at the end but leave that method unchanged, I don't want it flagged.  If however I insert a line of code or change something inside that method, it would flag it as changed.

I've used various diff tools, but all of them seem to fall short at telling you that lines have been inserted, removed or changed but couldn't tell what the changes were in any kind of logical fashion.  It would be nice if when I periodically rearrange the layout of my code file the diff tool could keep up.

Does anyone have such a tool?

Comment: Isn't that what source control change comments are for? :)

Comment: are you still waiting on support to get back to you, I'm interested to see what you find.

Comment: Still waiting.  They contacted me to ask me what dialect of C# I was after.  Told them I was looking for 2.0 (.NET 3.5) and asked for a price and if they'd be releasing a trial version and haven't heard from them since.

Comment: @Ben: sent you email inviting you to a beta copy for C# 3.0 on 9/4/2009. No response.

Comment: Ben has asked for and received a beta copy.

Comment: All: dunno where Ben went.  Production version has long been available, and you can download an eval from the website.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I use http://winmerge.org/

I don't think you can do what you are asking, because of the way the [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithms work for these tools.

Even if your functions get re-arranged, and your source file's functionality remains the same, it will still show up as a difference because of the nature of the LCS.

**EDIT:** 
This is a bit far fetched, but if you were feeling extra ambitious, you could write your own that tailors to your exact needs.

you could use regular expressions to pull out each method in a source file, and do the LCS diff on each method individually based on its name.  You could store your code a Dictionary (key,value) so that the key is the name of the method and the value is the string of the function. Then you just diff your dictionary_orig['method'] with your dictionary_new['method'].

Other than that, I don't know how you'd accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually, Winmerge has an option to detect moved text blocks. They will be marked differently from the ones changed or added/deleted.

Comment: I would still consider that "flagged"

Comment: Ira Baxter's posted an item that is potentially exactly the kind of thing programmers need for a diff, potentially it supports many languages.  I'm just waiting on a response from their support team to find out if it's actually everything it promises.

Comment: regular expressions? really?

Answer (score 9):

Check out our [Smart Differencer](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer/index.html) tool, which compares abstract syntax trees,
and reports differences in terms of the nonterminals ("language constructs")
that the ASTs represent, and plauible editing actions (insert, delete, move), as well as discovering consistent renaming.

At present, it only handles Java and COBOL, but it is based on DMS, which
has parsers for a wide variaty of languages, including C#.

**EDIT 9/8/2009: C# SmartDifferencer now available for beta testers.**

The tool already handles a consistent rename across the entire file as being
semantically trivial (on the assumption that other files reference
the renamed symbol accordingly), as well as renames within a scope. 
We plan on taking into account semantically trivial changes, such
as moving a method declaration around in a class for Java and C#.

**EDIT October 2010: Production versions available.**  [Eval downloads
accessible at the website.](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer/CSharpSmartDifferencer.html)

**EDIT May 2012**: You can [see a C# example at this page.](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer/CSharpSmartDifferencerExample.html)

One of the things it presently does not do is ignore semantically null edits.  A particular case in point is shuffling methods about in a class body; we all know this has no impact on semantics for C#.   Our tool compares syntax (via ASTs), not semantics, so it doesn't understand this particular nuance, and will consequently tell a user that "this  has been moved" rather than being silent.   We have plans to handle cases like this sometime in the future, but hey, every product has to have a version 1 :-}  [As a subtle point, shuffling methods in a Java class is also semantically null, but shuffling *fields* is not due to order of evaluation of initializers. I don't know if this is true also for C# but it wouldn't surprise me.]

Comment: Haven't checked this out yet, but will do when I get to the office.  Sounds very promising though - I'm excited to see what it's capable of!

Comment: Okay, so I couldn't figure out where to find a download of this tool to try it out for C# - just waiting for a response from their support crew.  I've got my fingers crossed that it's all I hope it will be.

Comment: The link to download the C# eval version is broken (at the time of writing this): http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer/C#FormatterEvaluationRegister.html

Comment: Richard's link problem is that his link is transcribed incorrectly. You can go to http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer/CSharpSmartDifferencer.html and download an eval from there, easily.

Comment: Ira, I'm surprised to find that I don't consider your answer to be spam. It does directly address the question. However, I would feel even better about it if your answer either included an example showing how the original problem would have been solved by the tool; or else perhaps a link to a demo which shows the same thing. Since it's a direct response to the problem, I would consider such a link to be a valuable contribution to [so].

Comment: @John: the web page linked points to an example page, under the rather short link labelled "here" (maybe we should change that).  And to be fair, it doesn't do exactly what OP specifies, but it comes pretty close.  It will tell him he moved his block of code, and that the block content didn't change, or if it did change, a "smallest" edit that explains the change.

Comment: @IraBaxter: that comes pretty darned close, and since your product is the only one I've ever heard of that comes close to doing this, I recommend you showcase it. If your product doesn't do all that the OP wanted, then a mention of what it doesn't do, and why it doesn't do it would be great.

Comment: @John:  oops, the index page referenced points to a general page, which points to C# page (and pages for other languages, each of) which has an language-specific example link.  I put an explicit example link for C# and some discussion into the answer.

Comment: Hey folks, just wanted to add this video clip discussion of SmartDifferencer from the CEO of SemanticDesigns who was giving a talk at the [GoogleTechTalks](https://youtu.be/C-_dw9iEzhA?t=2361)

Answer (score 6):

Would you be willing to do the compare on compiled assemblies?  If so, [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) has an Add-In available called [Diff](http://www.codingsanity.com/diff.htm) that will allow you to compare 2 assemblies.  This would definitely not care where/how your objects are arranged inside of the source file.

Comment: That's an interesting idea - and theoretically I don't need to diff files that aren't going into the VCS, and only compilable applications go in there, so this could work - as I said, theoretically.  I'll check that avenue out.

Comment: Its not a "perfect" solution, but it gives an interesting approach to see what is different from the other side of the compiler.  If you haven't used .NET Reflector, make sure to check out the other Add-Ins as they definitely make an already impressive tool even better.

And to whomever down-voted this response, please explain why.  If you find a flaw in my answer, you should step up and say what you find wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

The name  of this tool is CodeCompare. Try it - [CodeCompare](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/). Required feature called as [structure comparison](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/articles/structurecomparison.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's something I've been wondering also. I don't think it exists yet. There are 'functional' (as opposed to merely text-based) diff tools available for other scenario's. E.g. Microsoft Word integrates it's own diff/merge functionality (which can be scripted, so it can be integrated with e.g. TortoiseSVN), and there are also several tools available for XML which interpret xml files and do not simply consider them as text.

I'm not sure the added value of such a tool over a good text-based diff/merge tool would be compelling enough to merit developing it. OTOH this may just be the missing link solving the 'merge pain' we all feel when confronted with a difficult merge situation.

The difficulty is of course that you have to interpret the code in the same way the C# compiler does. For now the tool that comes the closest is indeed NDepend, I think. [This blog post](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/04/28/diff-tools-to-see-source-files-changes.aspx) explains some of its capabilities in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond Compare by [Scooter Software](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) rocks for this and it is cheap  ($30) too.

Comment: It's also been suggested Jeff used this while writing StackOverflow.  http://highscalability.com/stack-overflow-architecture

Answer (score 2):

I find [SemanticMerge](http://semanticmerge.com) to be very helpful. It displays the differences in a nice visual way, and is a breeze for comparing complex C# code.

Comment: As a long-term user of SemanticMerge, I just want to point out to any future viewers that this product is unfortunately no longer available as a stand-alone product, and has to be purchased as part of their SCM suite.

Answer (score 1):

I know you are looking for a tool.  But since I know of none, here is how I would accomplish this:

1. Read a book on compiler design
2. Lex/Parse your code
3. Create an Abstract Syntax Tree
4. Invent an algorithm for performing diffs on the Syntax tree
5. Profit!

Comment: Already considering this - I think it would be a great tool given that it's apparent that one doesn't yet exist.  The only issue is how do you lex/parse a class that has dependencies that aren't satisfied by the file alone?  It wouldn't work...

Comment: Maybe it would be a whole "project" or "solution" diff..  Your compiler already takes care of this so it shouldn't be too hard to figure out.
  
It would also be neat to make it language agnostic if possible.. So other langs could be added easily.  I'm sure quite a few people would pay for it as a product.

Answer (score 0):

I use [KDiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) and find that it works pretty well.  And is of course free.

Comment: OP: "I'm looking for a diff tool that can analyse my code and tell me what has changed on a construct by construct basis". Does DiffMerge? -1

Answer (score 0):

As many have suggested, I guess this kind of comparison will not be possible with available diff tools. Because their purpose is to say whether something changed and if you move a method from the beginning to the end, there did actually change something.

But what comes to my mind now is that you could do it by yourself. Basically invoking some diff tool, which will then return the newly inserted lines, basically the method that you have moved to the end of your file. Then you could do a comparison yourself, whether the changed lines where already present in your previous file.

Answer (score 0):

I think for comparing files online you should use http://www.diffnow.com. I am using this having option to choose language while comparing, its very nice

Answer (score -1):

DiffMerge from SourceGear is excellent, and is available at no charge.

http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/

Comment: OP: "I'm looking for a diff tool that can analyse my code and tell me what has changed on a construct by construct basis". Does DiffMerge? -1